# How to securely connect to a web api from a AngularJS site

Tags: php, web-services, security, rest, web

Being relatively new to web development, at least using client side technologies such as the AngularJS framework, I need to resolve a few queries before I can start my latest project.

I am writing an application using the AngularJS which reads/writes/updates data in a database. With javascript being client side I have chosen to write a PHP REST API to do the database queries, resulting in a secure username and password and a single database layer.

My question is, given my REST API, I will be using AJAX from javascript (which is client side) to invoke methods. How do I stop other sites from writing a script to invoke the REST API as well? Putting an authentication token in the javascript code isn't very secure, someone can just copy it.

Is a REST API the best approach for this problem? I am not adverse to learning new technologies or practices so please, any thoughts on better design patterns or methods of implementation are greatly appreciated. Unfortunately, due to my limited domain knowledge in this area, I have been unfruitful in my *Google Searches* as I'm not confident of the terms under which I should be searching.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your Angular application is living in the browser, your REST API will need to be publicly accessible from any random visitor's browser. You thereby have a public API, out of necessity. You can't restrict it; either visitors *can* see the data or they can't.

Essentially this is not significantly different from a traditional webpage though. In a server-side generated page, you output your data packaged as HTML and deliver it to anyone who asks. In a REST-API/Angular app, you deliver the data packaged as JSON to anyone who asks. Either way the data is equally public, though maybe the REST API is a little easier to "abuse" than scraping the HTML would be. It may be useful to deliberate employing some user behaviour tracking and throttling, if you want to avoid someone outright sucking all of your database dry; this applies equally to JSON based REST APIs as it does to regular web pages.

If you're also exposing *read/**write*** APIs this way, you're of course wide open to abuse.

The only way to make an API non-public is to require password authentication. If the users of your site must be logged in, then you can restrict the API to anyone with a valid session. This doesn't help much in the grant scheme of things if anyone can simply register an account on your site, but it needs more deliberation and provides slightly more manageability than a completely open API.

Admin-only APIs of course must be protected in this way, requiring an account which only you have the credentials to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was my thought/concern that the REST API root leaves you wide open for all kinds of connections, and there would be little you could do to effectively limit the originator.

Does that suggest there is a better approach available? I assume there must be a way of executing server side code from a client side application _securely_?

Comment: But again: get comfortable with the idea that you're **exposing this data on a public website anyway.** The technical distinction between a REST API and an HTML page is insignificant. Simply don't expose publicly what you don't want to expose publicly. I could write a program that crawls all of your HTML pages and extracts all the information out of it. In the end it gives me the same result as your JSON API would. It's a little more work to do it this way, but not significantly.

Comment: The data will be displayed on a site that is public, however, the user will have to login to view this page. My main concern is that a user could login, learn of a way to access the data via the API and then run away accessing the data from his own site.

Logins are only created **for** users, they cannot create them themselves, but if a new site were to open using the credentials of a user it could be difficult to catch initially.

Comment: Still no difference to a traditional website. What is user authentication? It's an additional HTTP header (typically: `Cookie`). Nothing more. Anyone can make an HTTP request with that header from anywhere any time. As long as they send a valid value for the cookie, they're "in". You can leverage the exact same characteristics for your REST API.

Comment: @deceze I am working on an Angular 5 web application which is about taking online exams and instantly telling the result. After attempting the test, the client side will request to the server for the list of correct answers and then it will compare user's answers with the right answers received from firebase server.

If a registered user can access the API of right answers stored on firebase server, he will be able to know the right answers which will be a failure.

Can you please advice me what can I do in this case. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Robert Send the answers to the server and have the server respond with whether the answers were correct or not. Never expose a list of solutions to the client. If your server doesn't have the capability to do the necessary computations (I don't know whether Firebase does or not), then you need to use a different server component.