# Hot to use the Basic Auth for REST systems with client in browser?

Tags: php, rest, authentication, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

When the Basic Authentication is in use, the credentials (64 bit encoded) are sent from the client to the server system and then are checked against the `.htpasswd` file on the server side.

I'm building an RESTful application: the server part is written on PHP, the client is / will be a JS application. So the client will send the credentials string to the server.

My problem is: I cannot understand, how this can work securely. Well, wenn I use SSL, the credentials cannot be stolen on the way. But they are written as plaintext in the client application code. So they can just copied and "reused" by another client. How to avoid it? Or do I understand the process wrongly?

Would somebody explain, how it works.

Comment: What exactly are you actually trying to protect from whom?

Comment: This sounds like a conceptual duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855574/how-to-securely-connect-to-a-web-api-from-a-angularjs-site/. It that's not the case, please add more information and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: You are right, it's a very similyr question. I've not seen it before I started my question.

Comment: Well, the question is actually nearly the same. But there has not got a question. Or I understand that question in a wrong way. I'll try to formulate my question different: I don't want the user to authenticate themselves (witha login form or something like that). I want an authorisetion for my client JS application, so that only this client application can get/manipulate data.

Comment: Yeah, you have the same misconception... :) Anything that happens in a visitor's browser is *not* "your client app". Forget about that concept. It may or may not be "your code" that is running in anyone's browser. It doesn't matter, you can't control it, it's not reliable. *The visitor's browser* needs access to your API, thereby *the visitor* needs access to your API, thereby your API needs to be public. Period.